# when I dont see api results I need to show no data found

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- when I type 1sport1 I see the results.
- when I type 1sport12 I dont see any results.
- so that type I need to show no dta found.
- and on clear all it should clear the text box.
- but the problem is this line `console.log("resp.json()--->", resp.json().[[PromiseValue]]);`
- I thought when length is 0 I will show the no data found.
- but I am getting this error.`/src/searchbar.js: Unexpected token (31:48)`
- I am commenting the below lines so that you can see output in the browser
  `// console.log("resp.json()--->", resp.json().[[PromiseValue]]);
  // display: this.state.noData ? "" : "none"`
- can you tell me how to show no data found when there is no data coming from api.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-cdn-14o1w

```
getQuery = async (type = "", search_tag = "") => {
    var url = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?tags=";
    const resp = await fetch(`${url}${type}&query=${search_tag}`);
    // console.log("resp.json()--->", resp.json().[[PromiseValue]]);
    return resp.json();
  };

  render() {
    console.log("this.state.noData--->", this.state.noData);
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.searchByKeyword} />
        <p
          style={
            {
              // display: this.state.noData ? "" : "none"
            }
          }
        >
          No data found
          <p>clear all</p>
        </p>
        {/* <Scroll />  */}
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using conditional rendering on [JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Change your code to following and it will work.

```
        <SearchBar onFetch={this.onFetch} />
        {this.state.data && this.state.data.length > 0 ? 
        this.state.data.map((item) => <div key={item.objectID}>{item.title}</div>) :
        <p>no data</p>}
```

I forked the sandbox and is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-voice-xrris)